# Tomcat infinite redirect loop

Tags: loops, tomcat, redirect, ssl, https

I'm currently in the process of migrating a Java6 - Tomcat6-based webserver from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2008 with extra security measures. However I've run into a problem with an infinite redirect loop when using HTTPS, it's configured identically to the previous server using a ForceHttpsFilter it should automatically redirect from http to https.

HTTPS configuration is as follows, the certificate is valid:

```
    <Connector port="443" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
        enableLookups="false" acceptCount="100"
        debug="0" connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" 
        compression="on" compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml" compressionMinSize="2048" 
        URIEncoding="UTF-8" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="D:\cms-java\Tomcat 6.0\cert\keystore.kdb"
        keystorePass="****" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https"
        ciphers="****"
    />
```

I've monitored with wireshark and it bounces between 302 found and a HTTP url response is returned.

I can't really find anything wrong with the configuration myself, but if you have any tips for me for things to check out, that would be great.

Comment: Can you show the code of your filter? The filter itself may not be the issue, but seeing the code could help understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem.
The server is behind a load balancer which has ssl pass-through set up, this resulted in the server only receiving HTTP requests over port 80, and thus the script couldn't validate the connection's security level, resulting in an infinite loop as it was redirected.